# Icons still not overlapping, while overlap set to true

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

In my mapbox style I have a custom icon image for the data points. Even though in the Position tab the `icon-allow-overlap` is set to `true`, one of the icons hides when zoomed out to level 12 or more.

Data points are loaded through geojson:

```json
var geojson = {
    "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "title": "Name of location",
            "description": "address"
          },
          "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [long, lat],
            "type": "Point"
          }
        },
        { more features here }
    ],
};
```

```html
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'token';
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'my style',
        center: [long, lat],
        zoom: 11.5
    });
    map.scrollZoom.disable();
</script>
```

For good measure I've also tried adding text to the label (an empty string), and setting `text-allow-overlap` to `true` as well, but to no avail. Clustering is not what I'm looking for.

I've found [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091083/mapbox-do-not-hide-markers-on-specific-zoom-level) other [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74745390/on-a-mapbox-map-how-to-keep-a-layer-always-visible-no-matter-the-zoom-level) describing this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44881683/mapbox-style-layers-are-hidden-sometimes-despite-layer-zoom-settings-equal-to-0) (even though I'm not using tiles but geojson), but none of the given solutions change anything for my usecase.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should include all the relevant code.

Comment: @SteveBennett I've added the code from my html, but the issue is already coming up when I'm working with the styles in the mapbox studio.

Comment: Including the style definition is useful - or at least the relevant layers.

Comment: @SteveBennett The layer in question is a blank new layer, with a geojson dataset uploaded in it. The geojson is included above, but I can't find any other settings related to hiding data points except for the `icon-allow-overlap`. I'm not sure if or where I can export the style definition for that specific layer from mapbox studio.

Comment: In your code you can do `console.log(map.getStyle().layers.filter(l => l.source==='mysource'))`

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround.
Instead of adding the data points to the mapbox studio style as a layer, I'm now adding them to my embedded map user side.

First making the features available:

```js
var geojson = {
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "title": "Name of feature",
                "anything": "anything you like, really",
                "this_data": "was used to add information to map popups"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [long, lat],
                "type": "Point"
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

Then adding them to the map:

```js
geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
    .addTo(map);
});
```

Finally style the divs the way you like, for example:

```css
.marker {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

Because they're defined in the html after the map has been embedded, they won't hide at different zoom levels in my experience.